# For/Loop/While in Databricks (Azure) SQL

Tags: sql, azure, loops, while-loop, databricks

Anyone know if I can do iterative construction (like loop, while, for) in SQL in Databricks?

Comment: write what do you want to achieve

Comment: I need to insert multiple columns (over 200) in my table. 
The diference between then is an argument in the substring function: the row_number. I started with 1 and need it to go until 250.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such direct approach available in SQL to iterate through the DataFrame. On the other side, `pyspark` have multiple functions to perform the looping over the data. It includes `map()`, `foreach()` and `pandas`.

Please find the example below:

```
# Using pandas
import pandas as pd
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
pandasDF = df.toPandas()
for index, row in pandasDF.iterrows():
    print(row['firstname'], row['gender'])
```

To know more, please visit https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-loop-iterate-through-rows-in-dataframe/#using-pandas-to-iterate.

Comment: Hello!
My whole code is in SQL e I am not very familiar with pyspark. Got to think about it. But thanks!